# android.view.InflateException, Android application crash when I try to open menu!

Tags: android

I wrote a game (using GLSurfaceView) application for Android 2.2. I have the following error when I try to open the menu:

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView

--------- Stack trace ---------

```
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder$MenuType.getMenuView(MenuBuilder.java:197)
com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.getMenuView(MenuBuilder.java:323)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.initializePanelContent(PhoneWindow.java:840)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.openPanel(PhoneWindow.java:417)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUpPanel(PhoneWindow.java:603)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUp(PhoneWindow.java:1319)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1648)
android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This happen on some phones (on mine the error never occurs):

My code is:

```
public class FinalKarate extends Activity
{
    private KarateGLSurfaceView view = null;
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");           

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        view = new KarateGLSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.item01:
                if ((view != null) && (view.isPlayingGame()))
                {
                    final boolean alreadyInPause = view.isInPause();
                    if (!alreadyInPause)
                        view.pauseGame();
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle(R.string.abort_game)
                    .setMessage(R.string.abort_request)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        //@Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            view.abortGame();    
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        //@Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if (!alreadyInPause)
                                view.resumeGame();    
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
                }
                return true;

            case R.id.item02:
                if (view != null)
                {
                    if (view.isInPause())
                        view.resumeGame();
                    else
                        view.pauseGame();
                }
                return true;

            case R.id.item03:
                if (view != null)
                    view.toggleSimplifiedMode();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I wrong something? Please help!

P.s: The xml file is the following (n.b.: I have replaced < > with [ ]  to post here in the forum):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/item01" android:title="@string/abort_game"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/item02" android:title="@string/pause_game"></item>
    <item android:title="@string/simplyMode" android:id="@+id/item03"></item>
</menu>
```

Other info:

```
--------- Cause ---------

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.(IconMenuView.java:140)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder$MenuType.getMenuView(MenuBuilder.java:197)
    com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.getMenuView(MenuBuilder.java:323)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.initializePanelContent(PhoneWindow.java:840)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.openPanel(PhoneWindow.java:417)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUpPanel(PhoneWindow.java:603)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUp(PhoneWindow.java:1319)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1648)
    android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
    android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
    android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Yes you did something wrong: you did not provide the menu xml file :) Please edit your question and append the xml file please.

Comment: @Heiko Rupp is right, the error is in your game_menu.xml#17, so please share it in your question.

Comment: thanks. n.b.: you can use Ctrl+K to format your code (even xml), no need to change the < and > characters! Also: this xml doesn't seem to contain 17 lines, and something is wrong creating an IconMenuView, but there is no icon attribute specified either. Are you sure you're trying to inflate this xml???

Comment: The error refers to Binary XML. Where I can found it? However on my phone (Samsung GalaxyS GT-i9000) it works. In another, (an ideos) it always fails. Both have Android 2.2.

Comment: The error refers to the xml you are trying to inflate. If it's the game_menu.xml, the error is in its 17th line.

Comment: Oh, how I can rectify thie xml?

Comment: The xml that I have posted is the game_menu.xml. I haven't a line 17. Only 8 lines.

Comment: The menu was generated by Eclipse ADT and I have no icons.

Comment: Some screenshots:

http://postimage.org/image/1l68wgmdg/full/
http://postimage.org/image/1l6h65cuc/full/

Comment: Thanks, i see. And what about your strings.xml? Does it also have a `<string name="simplyMode"...`, `<string name="abort_game"...` and `<string name="pause_game"...`?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="pause_game">Pause/Resume game</string>
    <string name="abort_game">Abort game</string>
    <string name="simplyMode">Toggle simplified mode</string>
</resources>

Comment: (Sorry I'm unable to format it)

Comment: no problem, it's short, readable, and the problem is not there either... You may have in your stack trace some more information about this error (some `Caused by` sections maybe) that might help us more. Would you please edit your question and paste them as well (if any)? Do you have any customization on your menu (eg. background)?

Comment: Ok, added more info in the post (the 'cause' at the end of the post).
N.B.: I have no customization in my menu (no background or others). My application is an OpenGL fullscreen application, could be a problem?

Comment: I can't figure out anything, at my end i can inflate a menu when in fullscreen... There is no indication anywhere in that stack trace, that the exception is caused in a line from your code? neither in subsequest `cause` clauses? Really sorry, but i have no idea what can be wrong there.

Comment: I think the problem was here:

 MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

in the (onCreateOptionsMenu).

Comment: However many thanks for your supports. Can you please give a try and let me know if the menu crash also on your phone? You have to start the game (touching screen) and select number of opponents (that are locked in the demo), then you can try the menu (try to abort the game). You can download it from (it's free): https://market.android.com/details?id=game.FinalKarateDemo&feature=search_result.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For other people with problems like his. The biggest reason why this has happened is because he didn't save the android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert inside the phone. He just called it. The inflater will give out a invocation target exception to this drawable if it doesn't exist.

Comment: maybe this is true.i will try and see.